# Apply Easing to Wave Modifier

Tags: modifiers

I am using the Wave modifier to apply a ripple effect to plane. However, I notice the waves are very robotic... is it possible to apply any easing to this process so it looks a bit more natural?

Closer look: https://bit.ly/3m1BDjv

Modifier settings:
[image: Screenshot of modifier settings]

Comment: You can make the modifier follow another object, or use a texture or both. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Hello, please post a diagram / Screenshot  of your problem and the expected behaviour so we can send you in the good direction :)

Comment: Here's an example of the video: https://bit.ly/3m1BDjv

Notice how jarring the waves are? isn't there a way to smooth this out a little bit so that it looks more natural?

Comment: Sorry I still don't know what exactly gives you trouble. Have you tried tweaking the settings in the modifier ? You can change the height / width / cycles of the waves

Comment: If *natural* is the desired effect as in your question, perhaps an *ocean modifier* is what you want? Used on a simple cube is very versatile. Otherwise, same as @Gorgious I'm having a hard time following the goal.

Comment: I totally understand what you want and what you need. But actually, if I subdivide a plane and add the wave modifier the animation is very smooth and eased. could you share your modifier settings? not sure what causes the jaggy animation in your example

Comment: What I mean by easing is having the ripples start and end smoothly. Watch the center one: it's moving up and down like a piston. It doesn't ease in and out 

@bstnhnsl https://ibb.co/CKbGRyZ Take a look here.

Comment: is your speed at .005 or something? I really can't reproduce what you are showing. my animation is really smooth with the same settings.

Comment: @bstmhnsl. Can you post a video of what you’re doing with the similar settings? I’m running 2.9

Comment: you should share your file (delete everything except the plane with the wave): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots Here it is: https://we.tl/t-toiLP0Ylqj

Comment: are you sure it's the right file? I barely see the waves...

Comment: I am, yeap. I'm trying to play with the settings in order to get this smoothed out a bit. If you want to send me a file you've made doesn't have this problem I'd be happy to take a look @moonboots

Comment: This seems to be a logical approach: https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/fqx88n/how_do_i_keyframe_animated_modifiers_such_as_the/ 

But if I could just use a curve bezier to ease the animated modifier, that would make 10x more sense

Comment: this is what I can do from scratch, what would be the problem with a wave like that? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=ElEogQoO" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ElEogQoO/)

Comment: @moonboots Yeah I tried it with your settings and it still looks pretty unnatural, totally robotic

Comment: @moonboots Actually it worked out great! Thanks for your help... Really appreciate it!

Comment: so what was your problem on your initial file?

Comment: I noticed that your rendition didn't have the solidify modifier. After matching up all the settings on both models, I'm concluding that's what the problem was caused by.